# console.log('\n'); after setTimeout inside for of loop

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about async and I'm trying to experiment with `setTimeout` to print out a string with a 50ms delay then finally print a newline after the loop is done.

With my current code it prints the newline before the loop is done.

```
const str = "hello world";
let ms = 0;

for (let char of str) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    process.stdout.write(char);
  }, ms);
  ms += 50;
}
console.log('\n');
```

Comment: setTimout(anyFunc, 0), giving time 0 ms does not mean that it will run just after 0 ms, this mean it will run very soon as possible when there will be its turn in event loop

Comment: I would suggest using promises

Comment: sure its printed out before setTimeout is done, its non blocking

Comment: @Mick Promises do not change the essential nature of asynchronous JavaScript callbacks at all. They merely provide a nicer way to work with those callbacks.

Comment: `setTimeout(callback,delay)` schedules `callback` to be run after `delay` elapses. And then the `setTimeout` call **returns immediately**. That is why you are seeing the results you got.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sleep = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const printSomethingDelayed = myString => {
  return sleep(200).then(v => console.log(myString));
}

const forLoop = async _ => {
  console.log('Start');
  const myString = "Hello world";

  for (let index = 0; index < myString.length; index++) {
    await printSomethingDelayed(myString[index]);
  }

  console.log('End');
  console.log('\n');
}

forLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Time is so small that you are not able to see the difference. Use 500 instead of 50.
Note: 1000 ms = 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = "hello world\n";
let ms = 0;

for (let char of str) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    process.stdout.write(char);
  }, ms);
  ms += 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `promise` or `async` `await` for this. The example of using `promise` is here

```js
const str = "hello world";
let ms = 0;

for (let char of str) {
 change(char, ms);
  ms += 50;
}

function change(char, ms) { 
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(char);
          resolve("done")
          }, ms); 
        }).then(function() { 
            console.log("\n")
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how asynchronous programming works :-)

In JavaScript, each block is pushed to stack synchronously and block gets executed. However, whenever stack recognizes any block as functions of WebAPI (in this case `setTimeout`), stack hands it over to the browser to handle the execution.

Once the task is finished by the browser, they are pushed back to stack (called as `callback`). When a stack is empty, these call back functions are executed by the stack.

In the given example, when stack sees setTimeout function, it hands over to browser for execution and move to next block which is `console.log()` and executes it. and now stack is empty and ready to execute callback functions.

If you want to print console log after setTimeout, you can be used `promises` or `async-await`.

If you want to learn more about asynchronous programming, do check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) by `Philip Roberts` at JSConfEU

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set every setTimeout to 0ms, the new line would still print first.

setTimeout (like all asynchronous functions before ES6) is not part of the JavaScript engine, so it doesn't go onto the regular call stack when the parser encounters it. Instead, setTimeout schedules browser API calls, and then parser moves on.

So when the parser encounters all the 'setTimeouts' in the for loop, the browser will make API calls and we are on our way to the next thing. The next thing happens to be a console.log() in your case. That goes onto the regular call stack, and executed.

In the meantime, the browser is making an API call, and the result of setTimeout gets put into something called the callback queue. Your function's returns will sit there, in line, in the expected order.

Now the call stack is clear. Here is the interesting part. Something called the Event Loop is constantly checking and checking and checking to see if the call stack is clear. If it is, it looks to the callback queue. The event loop then puts the function returns from the callback queue onto the call stack, and they are executed in order.

This is a lot of information and frankly I don't think any answer here will be good enough to solidify this understanding, so I highly recommend this youtube video on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ. This video gives the proper mental model for this exact behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = "hello world";
let ms = 0;

const print = function(i, ms, str){
    const c = str.charAt(i);
    if(!c){
        console.log('\n');
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(c);
            print(i+1, ms+50, str);
        }, ms);
    }
};

print(0, ms, str);
```